# Primitive of $z^2$ with disconnected domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am confronted with a task that almost looks like a trick question, but I wanted to make sure to get it right so I asked you.

I want to find every primitive of $f:B_1(2) \cup B_1(7i) \subseteq \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) := z^2$.

Obviously $f$ is a power series that converges everywhere, so by common formulae the primitive $F(z) := \frac{z^3}{3}+c$ for any $c \in\mathbb{C}$ clearly exists.

Is there any primitive I missed?

Comment: Yes, in comparison to many other things, it is a bit of a trick question, about connectedness ... The most primordial version might be "given a function $f$ on a subset of $\mathbb R$, with $f'=0$ everywhere on that subset, is $f$ constant?" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you have missed most of them.

If $c,c'\in\Bbb C$, then$$\begin{array}{rccc}F\colon&B_1(2)\cup B_1(7i)&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\frac{z^3}3+c&\text{ if }z\in B_1(2)\\\frac{z^3}3+c'&\text{ if }z\in B_1(7i)\\\end{cases}\end{array}$$is a primitive of $z^2$. And every primitive of $z^2$ in that domain is of this type.

Comment: I see. Thank you!